# Android 'Add-on' for app

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Don't know if I have the terminology correct, but I recently install TeamViewer Quicksupport from the Play Store. After it installed, I had to download an 'Add-on' for Samsung (I have no idea why it is needed, but I don't care, really).

This 'Add-on' has it own entry on the Play Store and you can download it without installing QuickSupport first, but you cannot 'Open' it.

I cannot find any information online on how to develop these 'Add-ons'. I do not even know if it is possible.

What I want to know is, how can such 'Add-ons' be developed and deployed. Any links to information would be greatly appreciated. I would like to find out if this would work for a design whereby you create a 'base' app with X features and then if needed, you can download 'Add-ons' to get other features? Kinda like modules?

Here are links to the Apps on PlayStore:

[TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market)

[TeamView QuickSupport Add-On: Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.addon.samsung)

Answer (score 1):

Without having looked more closely at your example, the "add-on" is likely just an app that doesn't have any activities declared as launcher activity. It doesn't show up on your home screen, because Android doesn't know what it would have to show you if you tried to open it.

The main app can then check if you have the add-on app installed, and communicate however it needs to with it.

There's no additional black magic here, just a regular app that isn't meant to be opened by the user directly.

Comment: Thank you. That totally makes sense. I am gonna give that a try, make a simple little app with a main activity (the 'base/core' app) and one with none but which has a couple of 'services' and see how that could work.

If that does work, it would open up a whole new way of designing apps as I do have an app with which I'd like to add extra functionality without adding it directly, ie. if a user wants feature X, they can download that additionally.